# RxJava2 connectableObservables - autoConnect(2) - why is it not waiting for 2 subscribers to call connect?

Tags: rx-java2

I have created a connectedObservable like this:

```
final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int j=1;j<=3;j++)
            list.add(j);

        Observable<Integer> observable = Observable.fromIterable(list);
```

this observable emits 1, 2, 3

now i convert it into a connectableObservable this way :

```
observable.publish().autoConnect(2);
```

i am therefore expecting since i passed in 2 to autoConnect that it will not trigger until 2 subscribers have been found. but instead it is executing on only 1 subscriber found.

let me show you what i tried:

```
observable.subscribe(new Consumer<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(Integer integer)  {
                Log.v("consumer1:", ""+integer);

            }
        });
```

I am expecting that this DOES NOT print anything to the log. but instead i get the following:

```
consumer1:: 1
consumer1:: 2
consumer1:: 3
```

> according [to the documentation](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/observables/ConnectableObservable.html#autoConnect-int-) on autoConnect(int
>   numberOfSubscribers):
>
> ```
> * @param numberOfSubscribers the number of subscribers to **await** before calling connect
>  *                            on the ConnectableObservable. A non-positive value indicates
>  *                            an immediate connection.
> ```

Comment: You are subscribing to the original observable. Why do you ignore the result of `autoConnect(2)`? Recommended reading: [fluent API part](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#simple-background-computation)

Comment: that was exactly the issue. thanks i got it.  if you need to make an answer you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In RxJava, you should not ignore the returns of operators:

```java
Observable<Integer> shared = observable.publish().autoConnect(2);

shared.subscribe(new Consumer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(Integer integer)  {
            Log.v("consumer1:", ""+integer);
        }
    });

shared.subscribe(new Consumer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(Integer integer)  {
            Log.v("consumer2:", ""+integer);
        }
    });
```

Recommended reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#simple-background-computation